# Does fancybox allow for a panoramic images? If so, how do I code that?

Tags: jquery, image, fancybox, panoramas

I am using fancybox 3.2.5. I would like to add some panoramic spherical images. I would like them to be interactive for the user. It would nice of them to start off with a slow pan to the right or left.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to combine fancyBox with some sphere-viewing script, for example, http://photo-sphere-viewer.js.org/ Embed this script in your page and then display it using fancyBox, just like any other inline/html content.